# How can I use a Python module in Pydev in Aptana on Windows 7?

Tags: python, module, aptana, pydev, raspberry-pi

I'm fairly new to Pydev in Aptana Studio 3, but thanks to some great tutorial videos I've got Python 3.3 running in Pydev just fine on Windows 7.

My reason for using Aptana/Pydev is for all the linty code-tidying goodness, but the bit of code I've been given which I need to refactor uses the [Rpi.GPIO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) module.

Works just find when I apt-get the module on the Pi, of course, but I need to do some massive tidying on Windows, then I can go back to IDLE3 on the Pi later.

It looks like you can't just dump the folder in a Pydev path and expect it to run, so I read the INSTALL readme, and the following thing happened:

```
D:\RPi.GPIO>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to RPi.GPIO.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing RPi.GPIO.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to RPi.GPIO.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'RPi.GPIO.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'RPi.GPIO.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'RPi.GPIO' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

So if anyone knows how to simply get Pydev to recognise this library, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

is happening because you don't have [Visual Studio C++ compiler](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express) installed which is needed to compile the code.

Also, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Milorad.So, I installed 2010, followed all the path settings in that other post, updated, rebooted... getting a different error ending "ValueError: ['path']" - see http://pastebin.com/NML05tLv. I can't understand why Linux is simply "apt get install <module>" and Windows requires 5 hours and 400Mb of download. Surely there's a better way to import a module?

Comment: @talkingnews I'm afraid there is no better way. The package needs to be compiled. This really can get nasty on Windows. As for the ValueError, I think you have something incorrectly set in the path (btw, I didn't have to modify the path upon VS 2010 installation). However, even when the path is set correctly I get this error: `source/py_gpio.c(296) : error C2040: 'setmode' : 'PyObject *(PyObject *,PyObject *)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (int,int)'`