# unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, visual-studio

I know there's another question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script) already, but I can't follow the answer. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8884982/1858363), I just need to add a variable. However, i don't know where the variable is created and where it's located. Normally, I work with files and folders only, so i don't know how to get add a variable. Since i thought the variable might be inside the bat files, i looked in vcvarsall.bat, vsvars32.bat, and vsDevCmd.bat. In the latter two files, i found lines saying `set VS110COMNTOOLS=`, so on the line directly after i put `@set VS90COMNTOOLS= C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\`
 as the answer said. However, the same error occured. I tried to install Visual Studio 2010 as the answer is for 2010, but since i already have VS 2012 i wasn't able to.

To summarize, where is exactly is the environment variable `VS10COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\`
? Thanks!

edit: sorry i confused VS 11 with 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the variable `VS110COMNTOOLS` to `[...]Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\`

Had the same problem in some qt project while using vc compiler. You have to copy each missing file to `[...]Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\` folder.

Just:
 - Read new error
 - copy the missing file located somewhere in `[...]Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\` folder

till no errors

EDIT:
You used `VS110`, `VS100` and `VS90` in your case (VS2011) that would be `VS110`

Comment: I don't see where the variable is. For example, the first two lines of vcvarall are [@echo off] and [if "%1" == "" goto x86]. I added  [@set VS110COMNTOOLS = c:\program files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\], but that doesn't fix the problem and i'm not sure if i've added the line in the right place.

Comment: these bat files included are corrupted (never worked for me). Set environmental variables manually

Comment: Thanks! After spamming system and user variables for multiple versions of Visual Studio something clicked and it works now!

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to import? Some modules don't play nicely on Windows -- best bet is to look at this [repository of .exe files for Python packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs).

Also, I've had the best luck by using all 32-bit versions of packages. I would recommend you do the same.

Comment: I was actually getting the error while trying to setup.py this https://github.com/gurgeh/selfspy/, sadly there's no exe, but I've gotten it to work now :)

Comment: Damn, the executables on the page you mentioned worked like a charm. I was trying to install zope and twisted on windows, and your solution is the only thing that worked since hours. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know that prepackaged binary version always works. But still, I would love to solved this dreaded error