# python pandas library installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried installing pandas library for python when when u typed

location > **python setup.py install**

this came up

> warning: no files found matching 'TODO.rst'
>
> warning: no files found matching 'setupegg.py'
>
> no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere
>   in distribu tion
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere
>   in distrib ution
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere
>   in distrib ution
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere
>   in distrib ution
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found
>   anywhere in dis tribution
>
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere
>   in distrib ution
>
> writing manifest file 'pandas.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
>
> installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
>
> running install_lib
>
> running build_py
>
> copying pandas\version.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\pandas
>
> running build_ext
>
> building 'pandas.index' extension
>
> error: ***Unable to find vcvarsall.bat***

Kindly help me resolve it

Comment: i have also installed Visual Studio '13 but still doesn't helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script

Answer (score 1):

easy answer since you are on Windows is just install the entire [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) distribution (free)