# unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, django, windows, batch-file, mezzanine

I have :

```
        OS: Microsoft Windows 7 (32bit)

        Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
```

I downloaded `Mezzanine` on my machine from it's official website. It's installation generate error `unable to find unable to find vcvarsall.bat` . I search for it's solutions and find that it can be compiler error and it needs c++ or c compiler to move forward. I have MS Visual studio 2010. so what i need more to solve this issue.

Looking forward to your assistance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script

Comment: @jarmod i opened Visual studio command prompt and try these commands but problem remains the same

Comment: vcvarsall.bat is in %programfiles%\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/), the "Minimalist GNU for Windows", by (1) [installing mingw](http://www.mingw.org/download/installer) and then (2) adding it to your PATH. Then, from the command line and from within the directory where `setup.py` is located, you can do this:

```
setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
```