# Matplotlib Basemap not working Windows 8.1

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I want to plot some GPS-data using python 2.7 using matplotlibs basemap.

I download the binary windows installer and it executes and run without any problems. However, when I try to import and run in python I get:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import basemap
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

I tried the

```
python setup.py
```

and

```
pip install basemap-1.0.8-cp27-none-win_amd64
```

in prompt which seems to be succesful. 
GEOS, which is a dependency should be involved in the Basemap installer but I installed OSGeo4w64 separately to make sure geos_c and **init** is in place.

I hope someone can help me out. This feels like it is well above my level.

I have ofcourse looked through other threads on this page, but none of them seem to offer a solution.

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

`from mpl_toolkits.basemap import basemap`

do this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Check [this](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html#installation) as well.

Comment: Check Path_to_Python/Lib/site-packages/mpl_toolkits\basemap. Have your more than one Pyton installation running? Are u using an IDE? Is it configured well? Can you post the error code with the capital B? I tested it and it seems to be the problem.

Comment: I have only Python 2.7 - At the moment the error is : Traceback (most     recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Mat\Desktop\mpltoolkits.py", line 4, in <module>
        from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py",     line 30, in <module>
        from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\pyproj.py",     line 50, in <module>
        from mpl_toolkits.basemap import _proj
    ImportError: cannot import name _proj
    [Finished in 0.5s]

Comment: There is a problem with your pyproj installation. Check if you have installed pyproj, you PATH is set correctly. You problem importing Basemap is solved anyway.

Comment: I did a succesful pip install pyproj. But Sublime Text 3 (only editor) returns same error.

Comment: I agree that it is probably my Pyproj that is messing with me, but when I run a 'python -c "import pyproj; pyproj.test()"' it returns succesfully, as did the pip install. I cant install via the Github master with a 'python setup.py install'. It returnds that it cannot find 'vcvarsal.bat'. Hope you have more patience, your help is most appreciated.

Comment: I know this issue: Set your PATH to the correspodning Visual Studio Version you have to use for Python. There are special Microsoft Visual Studio version like [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266). For further solution check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script).