# Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable not found when attempting to install MySQL-python via pip

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-2015, pip, mysql-python

I have `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x(86|64) Redistributable - 10.0.40219` yet while I'm trying to install the Pip package `MySQL-python` via Visual Studio 2015 Community, I come up with the error `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).` Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you've not got the appropriate path variable for vc set, so your python is trying to call vcvarsall.bat, but can't find such an animal.  Have a look at [Cannot find vcvarsall.bat when running a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script) for this exact same question (and some answers).