# Graphviz installation error

Tags: python, installation, graphviz

I am installing graphviz library or package in python using the command

```
pip install graphviz error
```

but I am facing the the problem that show in image. please anyone help me in fixing this issue.

[image: Error message appear during installation]
[image: Error message appear during installation]

Comment: Both errors say can't find vcvarsall.bat. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the future, it is much better to post the text of the error messages that you receive, rather than uploaded images of them.  With images, it is more work for viewers to see them, and they may be wary of accidentally downloading something unfortunate.

Comment: @ doctorlove now i am following error message
 Command 

  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2954): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Answer (score -1):

use vs prompt instead of cmd shell,  or use

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Comment: not worked following error occurs


  pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c(2954): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'graphviz/cgraph.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2